# C# Button Click and Private Variables

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax

So I'm trying to make a window forms guess the number game, simple but when I click guess no matter what the label goes up by one. I think it may be due to my variables as despite having them global userGuess still comes up as a local variable...`
Commenting out userScore removes the problem, but I still do not understand why the logic is failing

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Guess_The_Number_Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int userScore;
        private int randNum;
        private int userGuess;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBoxGuess.Hide()
            ;
        }

        private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randNum = rand.Next(0, 10);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxGuess.Text);
        }

        private void txtBoxGuess_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (userGuess == randNum)
            {
 //               userScore++;
                lbluserScore.Text = userScore.ToString();
                lbluserScore.Text = $"{userScore}";
            }
            else if (userGuess != randNum)
            {
                userScore--;               
                lbluserScore.Text = userScore.ToString();
                lbluserScore.Text = $"{userScore}";
            }
            else if (userScore < 0)
            {
                lbluserScore.Text = Color.Red.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
    private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randNum = rand.Next(0, 10);
    }
```

to

```
    private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        randNum = rand.Next(0, 10);
    }
```

That way, you'll set the member variable `randNum` rather than a local variable `randNum`.  You also want to check that you really are assigning the user-inputted value into `userGuess` properly.  My guess is that it's not, which means you never change the value of either of those variables, and the program thinks the user always guessed the right value.

Comment: Ah I'm such an idiot, thank you! So use to console applications I forget which way round it is. Trying to fix the userGuess error as we speak
EDIT: Fixed, cheers mate!